# Extract JSON XPath in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, xpath, xquery

I have the below JSON data. I would like to extract the HOME phone number. I do not want the work phone number. Would you write for me a JavaScript XPath expression for that?

```
{
   "Response":{
      "Details":{
         "MemberDetails":[
            {
               "DateOfBirth":"1969-04-03T00:00:00",
               "FirstName":"MIRIDA",
               "Gender":"M",
               "LastName":"MEARES",
               "MasterId":"rrrrr",
               "PhoneList":[
                  {
                     "number":"7088739304",
                     "type":"Home"
                  },
                  {
                     "number":"7088739304",
                     "type":"Work"
                  }
               ],
               "PlatformPointerList":[
                  {
                     "application":"",
                     "keyType":"AKAName",
                     "keyValue":"xxxxxx",
                     "source":"WPP"
                  },
                  {
                     "application":"",
                     "keyType":"xxxx",
                     "keyValue":"xxx",
                     "source":"xxxx"
                  },
                  {
                     "application":"",
                     "keyType":"xxxxx",
                     "keyValue":"xxxxxx",
                     "source":"ODS"
                  },
                  {
                     "application":"",
                     "keyType":"PERSONID",
                     "keyValue":"xxxxx",
                     "source":"EM"
                  },
                  {
                     "application":"",
                     "keyType":"PERSONID",
                     "keyValue":"xxxxxx",
                     "source":"WPP"
                  }
               ],
               "MemberId":"xxxxx",
               "MemberDependentCode":"xxx",
               "MemberSource":"xx"
            }
         ]
      },
      "MetaData":{
         "CorrelationId":"undefined"
      },
      "Status":{
         "type":"OK",
         "code":"200",

      }
   }
}
```

Comment: var respMemberDetails = JSONOut["Response"]["Details"]["MemberDetails"];
  var PhoneDetails = respMemberDetails[0]["PhoneList"];
var homePhoneDetails = PhoneDetails[0]["number"];


I used the above code to extract the first phone number . But the number could be a HOME number or a WORK NUMBER . 
hence I want to be sure that I extract the HOME phone number only

Comment: So whenever you extract the phone number right, check the type whether it's home or work... your type attribute will help you in getting the correct phone number

Comment: Helpful note: for all questions, readers like to see some prior effort applied to the problem at hand, so that they know they're not being asked to do free work. That's especially true for XPath queries, SQL queries and regular expressions, where the respective tags are filled with zero-effort questions. Would you be able to edit in an attempt at this first, @user1117723?

Answer (score 3):

There is no native method for parsing JSON structures using XPath in Javascript, so you'll need to use a library of some kind.

As you've included the JQuery tag in your question, jQuery-JSONPath would be a good choice: https://github.com/wilhelm-murdoch/jQuery-JSONPath

Using that, your query would simply be:

```
var path = $.JSONPath({data: JSONOut});
homePhoneDetails = path.query("$.Response.Details.MemberDetails[0].PhoneList[?(@.type == 'Home')].number");
```

See JS Fiddle here for a working example: https://jsfiddle.net/qy4end8k/

Answer (score 3):

Using the Saxon-JS library, you could use the XPath 3.1 expression

```
map:find(parse-json($input), "PhoneList")?*[?type="Home"]?number
```